# Creating a group variable

Tags: r

I have this dataframe `df`:

```
    A       B
    value1  a
    value1  b
    value1  c
    value2  a
    value2  b
   value 2  c
   value 2  d
```

And I'd like to have something like this

```
A       B  group
value1  a  1
value1  b  1
value1  c  1
value2  a  2
value2  b  2
value2  c  2
value2  d  2
```

That is, I'd like to create a variable that groups the same `A` values. How would you say it is the best way to do this?

Example

```
    id          code  
    2012-10-20  R     
    2012-10-20  L     
    2012-10-20  K     
    2015-04-28  K     
    2015-04-28  L     
    2015-04-28  L
```

Desidered:

```
    id          code  group
    2012-10-20  R     1
    2012-10-20  L     1
    2012-10-20  K     1
    2015-04-28  K     2
    2015-04-28  L     2
    2015-04-28  L     2
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason you'd want to create a separate variable for this?  It seems like it's just a duplicate of A.  Right?  Or am I missing something?  Also, it helps to use `dput` to output your data in a format that others can load.

Comment: Yeah right now this is just an exact copy of A. So you could do `df$group <- df$A` if you really wanted this. Is there something else you're looking for here?

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess i was trying to simplify the information too much. the A values are not the same as the group values, so it wouldn't be an exact copy of A.

Comment: could you please refine your question and/or the example df and output then?

Comment: you can use `?rleid()` from `data.table` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to do this is with `as.factor`

```
df$group <- as.numeric(as.factor(df$id))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use the values in A as a group, then you already have that. If you want to create an ordered grouping from A and A is an ordered variable (date, numeric, factor, etc) then do something like:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(group = dense_rank(A))
```

Comment: This is so much more complicated than what he's asking for.

Comment: It was not initially clear what he was looking for. The first part of the answer clearly answers his question - NOW. Sorry, not sorry.

Comment: And I've updated the answer now that there's been clarification. This clearly isn't too complicated and any remaining complication is due to ambiguity in the question.

Comment: If it's not clear what someone's looking for, ask for clarification rather than answering what you decide to be their question